# Finding a real matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = - I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there any real $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = -I$? If not how do I prove it?

[ I don't have any clue to start this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider what the determinant of $A$ must be.

Comment: $det(A^2) =I \implies det(A)^2 = (-1)^3 = - 1$ so we get a contradiction

Comment: Or its eigenvalues, which have to come in conjugate conjugate pairs if the matrix is to be real and its square not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks. This really solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $A$ lie in the set $\{i, -i \}$, since

$A^2 = -I, \tag 1$

for if

$Ax = \mu x, \tag 2$

then

$-x = -Ix = A^2x = A(Ax) = A(\mu x) = \mu(Ax) = \mu^2 x, \tag 3$

which implies

$\mu^2 = -1, \tag 4$

or

$\mu = \pm i. \tag 5$

Now if $A$ is a real $3 \times 3$ matrix, its characteristic polynomial is a real cubic, and has such has at least one real root; but such a root cannot lie in $\{i, -i \}$; hence no such $3 \times 3$ $A$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$, notice the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of odd degree, hence $A$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector $v$. It follows $A^2(v) = \lambda^2v$. Since $\lambda^2\geq 0$ we conclude $A^2\neq -I$.